# Can someone please support with the below error on an insert statement

Tags: sql, insert, distinct

I'm running into the following error when I run the below query. Can someone please assist with where this is breaking or maybe how I can re-write? I am trying to insert multiple record with the user_ID for X@vc.com for every database_id associated to X@ABC.com.

`"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."`

```
Insert into USER_DATABASE
    (
    USER_ID,
    DATABASE_ID
    )
VALUES      ((SELECT USER_ID 
            FROM USERS 
            WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@vc.com'),
            (SELECT DISTINCT DATABASE_ID
            FROM USER_DATABASE
            WHERE USER_ID = (SELECT USER_ID 
                                FROM USERS 
                                WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@ABC.com')))
```

Thanks in advance for help you can provide.

CHeers,
Roland

Comment: Are you sure there is only one userid for the username with 'X@abc.com'?

Comment: Your sql could be done more simply as a self join.  However you can fix your error by replacing `USER_ID = ` with `USER_ID in `

Answer (score 0):

Either of these 2 queries returns more than 1 row resulting in the error. Run them individually to find where the issue is:

```
(SELECT USER_ID FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@vc.com')
```

or

```
(SELECT DISTINCT DATABASE_ID
            FROM USER_DATABASE
            WHERE USER_ID = (SELECT USER_ID 
                                FROM USERS 
                                WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@ABC.com')
```

The correct query would be:

```
Insert into USER_DATABASE
    (
    USER_ID,
    DATABASE_ID
    )
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT USER_ID 
            FROM USERS 
            WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@vc.com'), DATABASE_ID
            FROM USER_DATABASE
WHERE USER_DATABASE.USER_ID = (SELECT USER_ID 
                                FROM USERS 
                                WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@ABC.com')
```

Assuming you need different userids X@vc.com, X@ABC.com

Answer (score 0):

As error says

> Your subquery returns more than one value.

You can find easily by individually running the inner query.

I think you are trying something like this:

For SQL Server

```
Insert into USER_DATABASE ( USER_ID, DATABASE_ID )
VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 USER_ID 
         FROM USERS 
         WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@vc.com'),
        (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 DATABASE_ID 
         FROM USER_DATABASE 
         WHERE USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID 
                           FROM USERS 
                           WHERE USER_NAME = 'X@ABC.com')))
```